# Pass a query and access SQL Server Database in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0, sqlps

I have a database named `'SQLDatabase'`. It has many folders like `'System _Database', 'R_Database','ReportServer'` etc.

I need to access `'R_Database'`.

Now `'R_Database'` has many folders like `'Storage', 'Security', 'Usage', 'Tables'.`

I need to access `'Tables'`.

Again, `'Tables'` have many tables in it.
I need to access a particular table named `'DB_Batch'`, and update it.

How should I?

This is the code I did for connecting to the SQL Server, and then the Table. But it fails.

```
$dataSource = ".\MSSQL"
$user = "userID"
$pwd = "password01"
$database = "SQLDatabase"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
#$connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$dataSource;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection.Open()
query = <query>..????
```

Now I suppose I need to pass a query. How should I?
I need to access the table first and then update it.

I even wrote the following code to end the above code, but not able to test as I am stuck.

```
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$result
```

I request, please help me with this. I have been trying this for days. I am using Powershell v2.0

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert/update a table, use a [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and its `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

```
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.connection = $connection
$cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO myTable (myColumn) values ({0})" -f $myValue
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```